# Parsing a line to take in both a character and a two digit number in C

Tags: c, parsing

I have an input file that has the line:

> e 45

I need a way to set the number "45" to an int variable named value.
I've tried to do

```
sscanf(inputfile, " %d", &value);
```

but value is just unchanged.
Am I using the function wrong?

Comment: `if (sscanf (line, " %*[^0-9]%d", &value) != 1) { /* handle error */ }` Note: `sscanf` parses a `char *` buffer while `fscanf` parses input from a file stream.

Comment: Please show the relevant code and not a hypothetical call to `sscanf`. Please state where the error is encountered. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 4):

Your use of:

> ```
> sscanf(inputfile, " %d", &value);
> ```

Is wrong on two points. First `sscanf` does not read from a file stream (which presumably `inputfile` refers to), instead the prototype for `sscanf` is:

```
int sscanf(const char *str, const char *format, ...);
```

Where the first argument is `const char *` which parses information from a buffer (which you most likely would fill with a call to `fgets` to read information from your file)

Second, with the string `"e 45"`, attempt to parse with `" %d"` results in a *matching failure* because when the `"%d"` conversion specifier encounters a non-digit, the conversion fails, extraction of characters from the input buffer ceases and the call fails.

Instead you will need to remove all non-digit characters before `"45"` before attempting to parse with `"%d"`. You can do that using the negated *character class* and the *assignment suppression operator* (e.g. `'*'`) with `" %*[^0-9]%d"` which causes `sscanf` to skip leading whitespace (which is not needed) and will *read and discard* all non-digits (making skipping leading whitespace with the `' '` superfluous) with `"%*[^0-9]"` (the `'^'` circumflex causes negation of the matching of characters within `"[...]"`) and then finally parsing the integer value with `"%d"`.

A short example would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {

    char *s = "e 45";
    int n;

    if (sscanf (s, " %*[^0-9]%d", &n) != 1) {
        fputs ("error: invalid format.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }

    printf ("n: %d\n", n);

    return 0;
}
```

(**note:** Always, always check the return of any `scanf` function)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/sscanfn
n: 45
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: `" %*[^0-9]%d"` will eat the sign of the integer -likely not important for OP.

Comment: Yes, that is a quandary that can't be solved by `sscanf`. With `"e-f-45"`, you are just getting `45`. Good point, but to remedy, iterating of the buffer and checking both the current and next char would be needed, and then a call to `strtol`...